# Concurrency error with CoreData and one-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency

I am currently developing an iPhone application using CoreData as a data persistence layer. In one of the scenario, I need to do some processing and batch update managed objects in the background not to block the UI thread.

Following [Apple's recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) on the matter, I have 2 different managed object contexts (one for the main thread, one for the background thread). Here is the allocation code (in my application delegate):

```c
// Object context for Main Thread
_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
_managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = _coordinator;

// Object context for the background thread
dispatch_group_t myGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(
    myGroup,
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
    ^{
        _bgManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        _bgManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = _coordinator;
    }
);

dispatch_group_wait(myGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(myGroup);
```

When the app launches, the main thread only fetches object for display, while the background thread gets fresh data from the network and update CoreData.

I use for that AFNetworking and make sure that all callbacks are executed on the background thread. Snippet:

```c
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webserviceURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
        [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
    ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Getting the managed object context created on the bg thread
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self bgManagedObjectContext];

        //
        // Snip...
        // Fetch objects, update them
        //

    } failure:nil];

operation.successCallbackQueue =
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
[operation start];
```

In the callback code, I fetch fresh objects based on their properties then update them. All is fine and peachy, until I start to update related objects...

My main entity (`Place`) define a unilateral *one-to-many* relationship to a `Keyword` (poor-man's full text search...) and when I re-index a `Place`, I start by deleting all associated `Keyword`s.

```c
// `self.searchWords` is a @dynamic property
for (NSManagedObject *word in self.searchWords) {
    // context is still the background thread's object context
    // and we're still on the background thread
    [context deleteObject:word];
}
[self removeSearchWords:oldSearchWords];
```

When reaching `[context deleteObject:word]`, I'm getting an exception: **An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts**

When I debug and inspect variables, I can see that:

- `self._cd_managedObjectContext` is the background thread's object context
- `word._cd_managedObjectContext` is the main thread's object context

I find it utterly confusing, I don't get why the fetched relationship would end up associated with a different object context.

I could eventually re-fetch the associated `Keyword` on the background context, then delete it from here, but is it the only solution in that case? Or am I getting / doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Clément,

I would suggest two things. First, background MOCs must be created on the thread under which they execute. Using GCD, you cannot claim any thread permanently. Hence, that leads me to my second point. Don't persist your background MOCs. They are cheap to create. I suspect that most of your problem is due to not keeping the MOCs in sync. The persistent store is really the mechanism to do that any way.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I actually ended up creating background MOCs on demand when I needed them. However, the problem I describe in my question is still here.

Comment: Clément, then you are having a database consistency problem. This is common to many multi-threaded database applications. IOW, you are not having a CD problem. In my case, I solve this problem by deleting objects long after they are used. You can also solve this problem by never saving transient objects. In CD, this is best done in a separate MOC. You then delete the MOC when you're done with the transient objects. Andrew